# According to the list to receive a string RID class MARKS

Tags: orientdb

In my database IM_0609 OrientDB version 2.0.8 is a class MARKS:

```
CALIBRATION_DATE:date.
DEVICE_MARK:string
DEVICE_NAME:string
END_MARK_NUM:decimal
MARK_NUM:decimal
PERIOD:decimal
SERIAL_NUM:string
```

In the class MARKS  I have created the index as follows: CREATE INDEX IDX_MARK_NUM on MARKS(MARK_NUM) NOTUNIQUE

I run the following query quickly:

```
select rid from index:IDX_MARK_NUM where key>=74118499 and key<=74118501
```

Results query:

```
#12:281829
#12:493194
#12:422739
#12:211374
#12:70464
#12:9
#12:352284
#12:140919
#12:329563
#12:259112
```

**Question: How do I write a query to get the list RID fields class MARS?**

Comment: `select rid from MARKS where MARK_NUM >= 74118499 and MARK_NUM <= 74118501`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No. I mean something like this: select * from MARKS where @rid in (select rid from index:IDX_MARK_NUM where key>=74118499 and key<=74118501)

Comment: And it's not working? What's the problem?

Comment: it is very slow.After IN instead of parentheses should be bracketed.

Comment: Why? I guess the IN operator accepts any collection

Comment: Can you try `select expand(rid) from index:IDX_MARK_NUM where key>=74118499 and key<=74118501`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from MARKS 
where @rid in [select rid 
               from index:IDX_MARK_NUM 
               where key>=74118499 and key<=74118501]
```

run for 51 sec.